# Plot appears empty

Tags: plotting, functions

When I define a function and try to plot it with its name inside the Plot[] argument my plot doesn't appear.

[image]

However, when I write the the entire function inside the Plot[] argument the plot works
[image]

How can I solve this to have the plot appearing in the first image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the argument,

```
f[x_]:=x^2;
```

Now to plot the function then you need to have,

```
Plot[f[x],{x,0,1}]
```